# Multiple Shapefile export as .csv in R

Tags: r

I have multiple around 100 and more individual ESRI format shape-files for different countries with multiple column information. I wanted to export them in .csv. Doing in Q- GIS adn ARCgis will take time. SO any lead would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the shape files iteratively into R using the `sf` or `sp` packages, extract the attribute table, and write it to a CSV. However, I think the best way to do this would bypass R entirely. You can use the GDAL program [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) from the command line to write the attribute table of a .shp file to a .csv as follows:

```
ogr2ogr -f CSV output.csv input.shp
```

This will write the attribute table of `input.shp` to `output.csv`. You can write a for loop in bash to do this for all your shape files. For a simple example, if all the shape files are in the same directory, you can run the following script in that directory:

```
for file in `ls *.shp`; do
  ogr2ogr -f CSV $file.csv $file
done
```